# Loading nock on intern

Tags: javascript, testing, intern, nock

I am trying to use nock (https://github.com/node-nock/nock) in my tests.

If I write `var nock = require('nock');` it won't find it as it is not loaded.

I have added the package in *loaderOptions*, and now I have to put `var nock = require('nock/index');`, because if I write the `require('nock')` it tries to load `node_modules/nock/main`, but it does not exists.

The library tries internally to load some modules nock brings with, but intern says `Error: Attempt to require unloaded module lib/recorder`.

I added nock into packages with: { name: 'nock', location: 'node_modules/nock' }

Any clue?

Thanks.

Comment: @LinhNguyen The post does not explains how to do it with npm modules, but helped me to to solve that one thanks! <3

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to load the library using the Intern's dojo node loader:

```
var nock = require('intern/dojo/node!nock');
```

Cheers!

Luis.